# Customized states not visible in Visual Studio 2019 work item view

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops-server-2019, agile-processes

I have an Azure DevOps Server on-premise and I customized the inherited process to have the additional "In Progress"-States "Ready":
[Default states and additional state "Ready"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiQLs.png)

In the web view this new state is shown correctly:
[Azure DevOps Server WebView with correct new state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URJOB.png)

In Visual Studio I only see the default states and not my newly added state:
[Visual Studio Work Item Detail with missing state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlZA6.png)

Any ideas what needs to be changed or is this an incompatibility between Visual Studio and the new inherited processes?

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the issue still occurs.

Comment: It was indeed a caching problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

**1**. Clear TFS caches

path %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache

**2**. Clear VS2019 caches
path %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache

**3**. Change the work item state to Ready via web page, then open the work item via Visual Studio and check the Work Item Detail page